# htacсess не хочет переадресовывать урлы с index.php/

Tags: .htaccess, index

Перевожу старый сайт на новый движок
Делаю переадресацию в .htacess
Иногда нужно переадресовывать подобные урлы

`index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html`

Делаю таким образом - не срабатывает

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa? [R=301,L]
```

Делаю таким образом, убираю "e" в index.php - срабатывает

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=indx.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-nefrita? [R=301,L]
```

Что нужно в подстроить чтобы он разрешал передресацию с index.php ?
Спасибо за ответ.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=indx.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-nefrita? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

может понадобится кому-то

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]


### ЗАДАНИЕ 1 ###
# с index.php/cat/c1398_Nasekomye.html на kulony-i-podveski/kulony-iz-yantarya-v-bronze-nasekomye
RewriteRule ^index.php/cat/c1398_Nasekomye.html$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa1? [R=301,L]

### ЗАДАНИЕ 2 ###
# с index.php?cat=1422 на kulony-i-podveski/kulony-poludragocennye-forma-obrabotannaya-biryuza
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=1422$
RewriteRule index.php$ kulony-i-podveski/kulony-poludragocennye-forma-obrabotannaya-biryuza? [R=301,L]


### ЗАДАНИЕ 3 ###
# c advanced_search_result.php?keywords=яблоня&x=0&y=0 на index.php?route=product/search&search=яблоня
# переводим русские слова тут https://www.urlencoder.org/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F&x=0&y=0$
RewriteRule advanced_search_result.php$ index.php?route=product/search&search=яблоня [R=301,L]

### ЗАДАНИЕ 4 ###
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%B8%20-%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B2%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8&photo=images/product_images/original_images/all/big/189_DEREVO_SCHASTYA_VIP_DEREVO_SCHASTYA_derevo_bolshoy_lyubvi___simvol_lyubvi_i_vechnoy_garmonii_3.jpg$
RewriteRule big_photo2.html$ derevo_bolshoy_lyubvi___simvol_lyubvi_i_vechnoy_garmonii_189.html? [R=301,L]
```